# How can I run this script automatically on startup

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, cron, game-development

I have a game server on my VPS, but i have a strong problem. When it reboots(for technical reasons or something) the game server doesn't start automatically. I use this script, which is located in /home/steam/csgo-ds:

```
#!/bin/sh
ln -s /home/steam/csgo-ds/csgo/*.dem /var/www/html/
ln -s /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
cd /home/steam/csgo-ds
chmod 777 * -R
screen -S "CS:GO Server" ./srcds_run -game csgo -usercon +game_type 0 +game_mode 0 -tickrate 64 -maxplayers 24 -maxplayers_override 24 +ip 188.116.46.148 -port 27015 +sv_setsteamaccount "XXXXX" -exec server.cfg +tv_enable 1 +tv_maxclients 0 +tv_port 27020 +tv_advertise_watchable 0 +map jb_dust2_final2
```

I have tried adding it to crontab, startup files and a lot more and nothing worked.
Operating system on the VPS is Ubuntu Server 64-bit 14.04 upgraded to 16.04

Comment: Hi,

Have you tried to use rc.local or init.d? I think that ubuntu has decided to use systemd at boot time. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 16.04 uses systemd as init system, Follow these steps:

```
chmod 744 /path/to/script
```

Now create a unit file:

```
vim /etc/systemd/system/csgo.service

[Unit]
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/script

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Set permissions:

```
chmod 664 /etc/systemd/system/csgo.service
```

Reload and enable the service:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable csgo.service
```

Now reboot and test it out.

Comment: I did that replacing /usr/local/bin/disk-space-check.sh with /home/steam/csgo-ds/startcsgo.sh and it doesn't work :(

Comment: Did you change `ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/csgo` in the unit file too?

Comment: I changed ExecStart=/path/to/script to ExecStart=/home/steam/csgo-ds/startcsgo.sh

Comment: try `systemctl restart csgo` then check for the screen

Comment: root@artur3126:~# systemctl restart csgo
root@artur3126:~# screen -r
There is no screen to be resumed.

Comment: remove `cd /home/steam/csgo-ds` and change the paths to absolute. then retry. You dont need to reboot, you just need to run `systemctl restart csgo` then check for the screen.

Comment: I did it, tried the command, tried reboot, but nothing. I think the problem may be that the server waits 10 seconds displaying a warning, since I'm running as root. Then it doesn't close to a deamon, but keeps running in console.

Answer (score 0):

there are different ways of doing this , the easiest way is to put 5 line of your code in :

```
/etc/rc.local
```

it will be executed automatically on each os boot
you should put your lines of code under this line:

```
exit 0
```

Comment: Can i put a link to my script instead of posting this 5 lines?

Comment: how did you add it to rc.local , can you put lines that you add to rc.local